# SQL SLECT two subqueries with multiple rows without any condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, distinct

I organise an online monthly competition where people give a grade to many users work.

I have a table `Votes` with each row containing the voter ID, the rated user ID and the edition of the competition (1, 2, etc.)

If there are 10 rated uesrs and I **vote for each one of them** (**mandatory**), I will appear 10 times in the table and this for each edition.

I would like to retrieve each user who voted as a JSON array grouped by editions.

This query works fine :

```sql
    SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("Nickname", Tbl.Nickname, "Id", Tbl.VoterId))
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT Votes.VoterId, Users.Nickname, Votes.Edition
        FROM Votes
        JOIN Users ON Users.Id = Votes.VoterId
    ) AS Tbl
    GROUP BY Tbl.Edition
```

Now, I want to get this and each user who got rated. So I tried this query :

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("Nickname", Tbl.Nickname, "Id", Tbl.VoterId))
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT Votes.VoterId, Users.Nickname, Votes.Edition
        FROM Votes
        JOIN Users ON Users.Id = Votes.VoterId
    ) AS Tbl
    GROUP BY Tbl.Edition   
) AS Voters, (
    SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("Nickname", Tbl.Nickname, "Id", Tbl.RatedUserId))
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT Votes.RatedUserId, Users.Nickname, Votes.Edition
        FROM Votes
        JOIN Users ON Users.Id = Votes.RatedUserId
    ) AS Tbl
    GROUP BY Tbl.Edition   
) AS RatedUsers
```

I get the following error :

> #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

I don't understand why it is an issue because each subquery returns as many rows as the other.

Comment: You're putting these subqueries in the SELECT list, and in that position they are only allowed to return 1 row.

Comment: Show us a few row of result from each query, and also the wanted combined result. (All as formatted text, no images.)

Comment: Here's a PasteBin : http://pastebin.fr/70226 @jarlh

Comment: To expand on @jarlh's first comment, it's the outer "SELECT (...) as RatedUsers" that is causing the problem. Even if this worked, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with it as it wouldn't add anything to your overall logic? For it to work, everything within this select statement would need to resolve to a single row/string as this outer statement is not selecting from a table. Conceptually you are writing something like SELECT ('ABCDEF') as  RatedUsers which makes sense for a string like 'ABCDEF' but makes no sense for multiple rows of data

Comment: Do one query. JOIN users twice.